# Should the flask folder be a part of my project?

Tags: git, web-applications, flask

I have a `flask` web app. The flask folder is pretty heavy. Do I need to add it to my git repository in order for the app to work with Heroku? Should I add the `flask` folder to git ignore and not commit it to my git repository?

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you can use a [`pip` requirements file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip) to your project and specify that you need Flask and Heroku's build process will download and install Flask for you:

```
# requirements.txt
Flask==0.9
```

I would recommend reading through [Heroku's tutorial on developing with Python on their platform](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python) to learn more about `pip` and `virtualenv`.  You'll find them both very useful if you continue to work with Python 2.x.